# Can't get @media queries to work with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I just can't seem to get @media queries to work in bootstrap. Take this one for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.buttonspace {
margin-left:20px;
}
}
```

The margin shows up but it also shows on devices <992px wide. What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you post a demo of the output? Nothing wrong with current code.

Comment: you may also be including bootstrap after your own css, in that case bootstrap's media queries will override yours

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted seems to be fine, so I assume this must be a classic example of forgetting to set the viewport. You need to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` in order for CSS media queries to be understood correctly by the browser.

(This could have been a comment, but alas I have no rep for that.)

Comment: Thanks but already got that! Really can't work this out, I'm sure there's something simple I'm overlooking...